# Stop redirect in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function which verifies if some fields have been filled out (if length > 0) before submitting. If it fails to submit, I don't want to redirect the client at all. Right now, I have the following:

```
function onSubmit()
{
  if (verify()) //This function will throw alert statements automatically
  {
     document.getElementById('my_form').submit();
     return void(0);
  }

  else
  {
     document.getElementById('my_form').action = null;
  }

}
```

However, it doesn't matter if verify() returns true or not, I still redirect the client and wipe her inputted fields. How do I keep the client on the page if a required field is blank? (I don't want to lose her currently filled out form...)

Also, I can't use the slick JQuery libraries, since it's not supported on some older browsers. (I'm trying to capture the most general audience.)

Comment: Why aren't you returning false? Why return void(0)? Did you try alert(verify()) to see what it returns? Also setting the action to null after the form is submitted is not good. If you have server side code, then it's okay since javascript executes before server side code. If javascript returns false, server side shouldn't execute anyways.

Comment: What older browsers are not supported by jQuery? It sounds as though you are seriously misinformed.

Comment: How is the `onSubmit()` function being invoked?

Comment: `document.getElementById` is supported by less browsers than `jQuery`

Comment: @zzzzBov IE didn't support the validate function from JQuery. I tried the newest back to IE7.

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 I changed my code to return false, and I'm still redirecting for some reason. I'm stepping through my JavaScript using chrome, and my verify function seems to work correctly, and I return false...

Comment: Yeah, if you're supporting anything before MSIE 6 you've got a development problem, not a scripting problem. Try to stick to the 3 version rule, don't create reverse compatible code for anything that is older than 3 versions.

Comment: @drlouie-louierd That may have come out wrong. I'm supporting up to IE7, so I tried IE7,8, and 9.

Comment: Just add onSubmit to your <form> tag and route that through your script. This will stop all browsers from submitting:

<form onSubmit="runScript();">

Comment: That's what I had to do in the end. I used tereško answer, which overrides a good deal of my server side code.

Comment: @zzzzBov , adding a humongous library just to validate a form would be kinda wasteful.

Comment: @Sal, [jQuery doesn't have a `validate` function](http://api.jquery.com/). If you want it, you'll have to use a plugin.

Comment: @tereško, jQuery is hardly a humongous library, and it's not simply about validating a form, it drastically simplifies event binding and animation as well. That all being said, I agree that it's not necessary to rely on jQuery for everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would try to solve this:

```
document.getElementById('my_form').onsubmit = function( e ){
    var event = e || window.event;


    // function payload goes here.


    event.returnValue = false;
    if ( event.preventDefault ){ event.preventDefault(); }
    return false;
}
```

Can be used with [event delegation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) too.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to comment simple 'thank you' messages on this, but this had me breaking my head for a while. (I program Java server side code,  JS is just plain brutal for me.) So, thankyouthankyouthankyou!

Answer (score 3):

return false to the form!

```
<form onsubmit="return onSubmit()">

function onSubmit()
{
  if (verify()) //This function will throw alert statements automatically
  {
     return true;
  }

  else
  {
     return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, but returning false doesn't seem to work. I think the problem may be server side...

Comment: The important bit on this is the <form onsubmit="return onSubmit()">
If you don't have the return in the form then the resturn value of the function never bubbles up to the form. Glad you got an answer.

Answer (score 1):

to stop the form from submitting, return false from your onSubmit